# Access main activity FloatingActionButton from Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a an activity with 3 fragments. Each fragment has to have a FAB with different icon an action. 
The FAB is defined on the main activity layout. Now I saw that I cannot access it from fragments. How can I do it?

Here's my code:
main_activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp">


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

my fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/contact_recycleview">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

inflating the fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.filters_fragment,container,false);

    myrecyclerview = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.contact_recycleview);
    recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterCall(getContext(), lstCall);
    myrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager((getActivity())));
    myrecyclerview.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    myrecyclerview.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

    return v;
}
```

so here I'll like to change icon an action, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Step 1 create interface**

```
  public interface FabButtonClick {
         void onFabClicked();
         void onFabClickedTwo();
    }
```

**Step 2 : inside activity**

```
 FabButtonClick fabButtonClick ;

inside `oncreate()` of activity

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


switch(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()){
case 0: 
fabButtonClick.onFabClicked()
break;
case 1: 
fabButtonClick.onFabClickedTwo()
break;
etc
}
                    
                }
            });
```

**Inside of activity only**

```
private void setListener(FabButtonClick interface){
    fabButtonClick =interface;
}


fragment implement FabButtonClick
```

**Inside fragments onViewCreated**

```
((YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME)getActivity()).setListener(this)
```

Overridden method from interface now let you handle fab clicks in Fragment

Comment: If you can use `((YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME)getActivity()).someMethod()` directly then why need to create interface?

Comment: for abstraction . if you those clicks in different fragments say 10 fragments with different implementation ... you have to create 10 different methods in activity right ? plus how will you handle sending data after button click if thats the case?

Comment: Hi, I had implement your answer, however when I click on either fragment the action is always the same....

Comment: you need two create two more method in interface and and call those method according to viewpageradapter getcurrent position

Comment: Now the problem is with the fab icon, how can I change the icon on each fragment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194017/discussion-between-akshay-shahane-and-paula-perez).

Comment: Please take care about code formatting and your spelling the next time, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Android developer guide recommend the following way to do `Activity`, `Fragment` communication.

`Fragment` access `Activity` by listener. `Activity` access `Fragment` by `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()`

So you have two ways to use the `fab`.

First, directly access the `fab` in `Fragment`

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    MyFragmentListener listener;

    void myFunction() {
        FloatingActionButton fab = listener.getFab();
        ...
    }
}

interface MyFragmentListener {
    FloatingActionButton getFab();
}

class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragmentListener {
    FloationActionButton fab;

    @Override
    FloationActionButton getFab() {
        return fab;
    }

    @Override
    void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
        if(fragment instanceof MyFragment) {
            ((MyFragment) fragment).listener = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Second, Call `Fragment`'s function when `fab` is clicked

```
//In Activity
fab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    for(fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        if(fragment instanceof MyFragment) {
            ((MyFragment) fragment).someFunction();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: and how to change the icon on each fragment?

Comment: Use the first way, `listener.getFab().setImageResource(res_id)`

Answer (score 1):

Add Floating action buttons to your fragments. Add it in Fragments layout. In this way it will be easier and clearer approach.

Answer (score 0):

Call this from Fragment

```
 Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).someOperationOnFab();
```

where someOperationOnFab() is defined in MainActivity

```
 public void someOperationOnFab(){
     yourFab. blah
}
```

Comment: Nice solution!!

Comment: But I think you need to call like `((MainActivity) getActivity()).someOperationOnFab();`

Comment: `MainActivity.getActivity()` is not possible!!

Comment: that works but there is the same action for all the fragments

Comment: why not use interface ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm using the MainActivity floating action button in my fragments...

In MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...

    MyViewModel mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    if (fab != null) mViewModel.setFab(fab);
}
```

In MyViewModel.java:

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private FloatingActionButton mFab;

    public void setFab(final FloatingActionButton fab) {
        mFab = fab;
    }
    public FloatingActionButton getFab() {
        return mFab; 
    }
    public void listenToFab(View.OnClickListener ocl) { 
        if (ocl != null) 
            mFab.setOnClickListener(ocl); 
    }
}
```

Then, in each fragment, implement View.OnClickListener:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
```

then call the ViewModel's 'listenToFab' method passing in the fragment as the listener parameter

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
    mViewModel.listenToFab(this);
}
```

Note that in MainActivity.java this line is:

```
MyViewModel mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
                                               ^^^^
```

And in the fragments this line is:

```
mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This way each fragment gets the same ViewModel in which the fab was set in MainActivity.

(edited to correct potentially misleading variable name)